# Error 450 en VBA: Argumentos incorrectos en la llamada al procedimiento

Tags: excel, vba, listview, textbox

Estoy trabajando con un código VBA y me encuentro con el error 450 que dice “Argumentos incorrectos en la llamada al procedimiento”.

El error ocurre en la línea:

```
li.SubItems.Add Format(rng.Cells(i, j + 1).value, "h:mm")
```

He revisado el código y parece que todos los argumentos necesarios están presentes en la llamada al procedimiento. Aún así, sigo recibiendo este error. (el userform carga automaticamente la fecha del dia en textbox y traslada desde la Hoja Horas todas las lineas que correspondan a la misma fecha fecha a un listview con el resto de columnas de la misma hoja)

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a entender qué está causando este error y cómo puedo solucionarlo? Cualquier ayuda sería muy apreciada.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: viendo la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications), en el ejemplo coloca los segundos, capaz será por eso. La verdad que no lo puedo probar, sino la otra que podes hacer es pasarle la opción de 'Short Time' y después hacerle un substring del momento del día o al texto de 'h:mm' agregarle los segundos directamente y quede como 'h:mm:ss'. Proba diferentes casos y no esta mal que le agregues un substring al resultado del format o que cortes la fecha ya que la funcíon hace eso interamente. No

Comment: muchas gracias por tu observación. Lo revisaré

Comment: El problema podría estar en cómo se está accediendo al valor de la celda. Asegúrate de que rng.Cells(i, j + 1).value esté devolviendo un valor que pueda ser formateado como “h:mm”. Asigna a un variable el valor de rng.Cells(i, j + 1).value y con un punto de interrupción ve mirando los valores, ya que igual obtiene valor nulo